# JQ Pulling Inconsistent Results

Tags: iteration, jq

If I run this very straight query on my json data from an aws command I get a correct result as to how many aws server instances I have in an account:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId'
```

Produces a list of 47 instance IDs which corresponds to the number of server instances I have in the account. For example:

```
i-01adbf1408ef1a333
i-0f92d078ce975c138
i-0e4e117c44b17b417
and on up to 47 instances
```

This next query still produces the correct number of results:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [( .InstanceId ) ]'
```

However, if I add a query to include the name tags of the servers I get dramatically less number of server instances reported:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [( (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value), .InstanceId ) ]'
```

This is the output of that command:

```
"i-08d3c05eed1316c9d"
"USAMZLAB10003","i-79eebb29"
"EOMLABAMZ1306","i-dbc98af4"
"USAMZLAB10002","i-d1dc1d83"
"i-0366c9bf18d27eb96"
"i-04d061334bc2f2d6b"
"USAMZLAB10007","i-f7a680a7"
"i-090e84eff4fece2b3"
"EOMLABAMZ1303","i-7cc98a53"
"EOMLABCSE713","i-08233926"
"i-0705eb3039cd56e04"
jq: error (at <stdin>:5013): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

For some reason that query reports that there are only 11 aws server instances (when there should be 47). It does report that there are servers with and without name tags. But it's not reporting the correct number of servers.

It also produces the jq error "Cannot iterate over null".

I have put the original JSON into this paste:

[Original JSON](https://pastebin.com/dUVthQKh)

How can I make the error more verbose so I can find out what's going on?

And why does adding the name tag to the query dramatically reduce the number of results?

Comment: Provide the JSON input to help us reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you, I will tomorrow. I appreciate your response. If I wasn't dead at the end of a long day I would do that now. Apologies!

Comment: Hello, I've put the original JSON into the OP. Sorry for the delay and thanks for any input you may have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your json, not all instances have a set of `Tags` thus the error.  You would have to handle it or substitute an empty array in its place with `(.Tags // [])`.  But overall, I would write it like this:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] | [ (.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name), .InstanceId ]
```

Comment: Ok great! Instead of substituting an empty array, how would I substitute another character? So instead of an empty array, I would get '-' (a dash) or even an empty space ' ' as the output? Could I write that as `(.Tags // - | from_entries.Name)` ?

Comment: You need to substitute the tags array with an array, but you're essentially trying to substitute the name with a dash. So it should be `(.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name // "-")`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the error more verbose so I can find out what's going on?

You could use `debug`.

> why does adding the name tag to the query dramatically reduce the number of results?

Because your jq program is at variance with your expectations; specifically, you have overlooked what happens when .Tags evaluates to null.  To understand the mismatch, consider:

```
$ jq -n '{} | .Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value'
```

Another issue is the handling of empty arrays. You might like to handle the case of empty arrays along the lines suggested by the following:

```
$ jq -n '{Tags: []} | (.Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) // null'
$ null
```

### One solution

If you want `null` to appear whenever there isn't a tag:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[]
| [ ((.Tags // [])[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value) // null,
    .InstanceId  ]
```

Given your input, the first two lines of the output would be:

```
[null,"i-08d3c05eed1316c9d"]
["USAMZLAB10003","i-79eebb29"]
```

### Variant using `try`

```
.Reservations[].Instances[]
| [ try (.Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) // null,
    .InstanceId  ]
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But there are no isolated `[]` statements in my code. I am iterating over the `.Reservations[].Instances[]` and the `Tags[]` arrays. If I remove teh `[]` statement the query breaks. Sorry if I'm not following you, but I'm not sure why this is considered a black hole, since I'm iterating over arrays.

Comment: The point is that there are empty arrays in your data, and your code does not take that into account.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Thanks. I'm still trying to work out the syntax I need. If you could help I'd appreciate it. Still learning jq.

Comment: I already showed how to use `// null`. You might be more comfortable with `if length == 0 then .[] | ... else null end`.  If you need further help, please provide a small but representative sample of the input that jq sees.

Comment: OK thanks. I will give that a try and circle back if I have any more questions. Also I did post a link of the json input in the OP. Here it is again: [Original Json](https://pastebin.com/dUVthQKh)

Comment: By "small but representative" I was referring to [mcve].

Comment: I took out some extraneous code. I don't think there's any more I can reduce without losing a the meaningful part of the command that folks can use to reproduce the problem.